# Force SASS to do math

Tags: sass

Trying to do math inside my loop.

```
@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  ul li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    z-index: length($colors) - #{$i};
  }
}
```

But what I get in CSS, for example, is:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 8-2;
}
```

How can I force SASS to do math and get:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 6;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the *$i* value as a string in the *z-index* property. If you want to calculate the value correctly you should do it:

```
$length: length($colors)
@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  ul li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    z-index: $length - $i;
  }  
}
```

Also I recommend you to set a variable with the value of length to prevent multiple calls to this function.

Regards.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! Set a variable is good idea, but I'm not using server side SASS, so it's not necessary for me. Anyway, good practice, agreed.